# Going nuts: Gemfile.lock permission problem when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, capistrano, passenger

I'm getting the following error when executing my rails application:

`Permission denied - /path/to/app/Gemfile.lock from bundler/definition.rb` :

```
Permission denied - /srv/www/app/releases/20110312182822/Gemfile.lock 
Error message: Permission denied - /srv/www/app/releases/20110312182822/Gemfile.lock
Exception class: Errno::EACCES 
Application root: /srv/www/app/current
```

I've tried chmoding, chowining, deleting Gemfile.lock, running bundle install on the server ...

I haven't found any help on Google.

Any hints?

The only thing that I suspect is that I'm deploying using my server's root account. Hmm...

Comment: Have you added `/path/to/app` when posting this question or is that the actual text from definition.rb!

Comment: LOL, no, this is the complete text: Permission denied - /srv/www/app/releases/20110312182822/Gemfile.lock Error message:
Permission denied - /srv/www/app/releases/20110312182822/Gemfile.lock
Exception class:
Errno::EACCES
Application root:
/srv/www/app/current

Comment: I'm new to rails and know very little about apache permissions. I'm having the same problem. However, I'm not deploying with capistrano. I have apache and passenger installed. Afraid to add one more problem to debug. Will please assist me by listing step by step how you solved your problem? Just like you I could find anything on the web. I've been working on this error for 10 hours now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**: The problem was that I was deploying as a root user. I went back and created a 'deploy' user on the server, added it to the sudoers, changed permissions and ownership of the application directory, and redeployed.

It worked. I was about to shoot myself. Too bad; now I'll have to find another excuse.